# How to change the color to particular word in an array string? : Javascript/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I have a caption on the website banner which will display with the given time interval (captions were declared in an array).

I wanted to change the color of specific words in the set of strings. Like, want to change the color of Lucky, Vasudeva, Krishna.

```js
var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
var text = ['Ajay garidipuri lucky ', 'Vasudeva Vijay', 'Mude krishna unlucky '];

function display(i) {
  if (i >= text.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  caption.innerHTML = text[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    display(i + 1)
  }, 6000)
}
display(0)
```

```css
.content-video h1 {
  font-size: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 25%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

#caption {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-video">
  <h1><span id="caption"> </span></h1>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well.. To the best of my knowledge there is now way change the style of a specific word in a string unless you wrap your word with it's own tag (like  or ) and give this tag a style/class of the color that you want.

This means that instead of doing : `caption.innerHTML = text[i];` You will need to append an inner `<span>` or other tag inside it.

So your final HTML should look something like:

```
<span id="caption"> Ajay garidipuri <span class='lucyColor'>lucky</span></span>
```

Comment: @AJAYGARIDIPURI , I don't understand exactly what you mean , but the time interval and the fact that you are changing the captions should not be a problem as long as you know which words you want to have a specific style